# How to simulate printer with two trays in Windows

Tags: windows, printing, c#, simulation

I am developing an application to print PDF files on two different types of paper, namely red and blue paper, using tray1 and tray2, respectively.

As I am still in the trial-and-error phase of development, I wish to explore possible simulation options on Windows to ensure functionality before proceeding with actual printer testing. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: [This seems like a question for Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989772/printing-multiple-page-pdf-file-using-different-trays).  If you want to be able to use 2 printers, or a single printer with multiple trays, you will have to program the print portion of your application to support that. How that is accomplished is NOT within scope here at Stack Overflow. We are not a discussion forum, so seeking our "insights" in a subject, is not a well defined question that can be answered.

Comment: The [Bullzip](https://www.bullzip.com/) PDF printer is [said](https://www.bullzip.com/kb/paper-trays-on-the-pdf-printer/) to be able to emulate trays. See if the link works for you.